# This phrase should contain "a"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, formal-language

I am wondering whether the following phrase should contain **a** or not?

> Although I have worked with many students in my role as **a** teacher, I can remember her easily because she was in the top 10% of my class.

Comment: Most native speakers would include the indefinite article.

Comment: I personally haven't seen any article or native speaker saying without the preposition (either a or the) for about 36 years' relationship with English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Professional, royal, government, and family roles, such as *teacher*, *boss*, *co-worker* can be considered abstract and don't need the article, especially after *as*.

But it's OK to use it as well, because the person *is* a teacher, so the noun also works non-abstractly.

It's slightly more formal/professional to omit the article.